# Installing theme, Problems with icons ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, themes, icons, ubuntu-tweak

I was installing [Flattastic theme](http://nale12.deviantart.com/art/Flattastic-07-01-2014-4249132553). Copied the unzip files to `/usr/share/themes` and selected theme using `tweak tool`. Ubuntu 12.10

- Problem 1: No flattastic related icons are listed in icon-theme.
- Problem 2: Icons in bottom panel are blurred.

How to correct them?
Thanks in adavance

Comment: did you restart you pc?

Comment: Nope. Let me now

Comment: No change in options even after restart

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Moka icons. I had to adjust the permissions for the files before copying them in /usr/share/icons, but then, even though the permissions were ok, i also had to copy the icon folder to .icon also. Try doing everything i posted, and see if it works.